# One-Step Equations

Tags: math, division, equation, negative-number

what is -2.4=z/-4

The division sign is meant to be a fraction. I tryed this equation on my calculator and I just cannot find the answer and this assignment is due tomorrow. Please someone help me. I am just now learning hw to do stuff like this and my teacher assigned this problem and it is super hard for me, again I tried it on my calculator but i dont know what to do so if you could help me it would be great.

Comment: z = -2.4 * -4 = 9.6 https://quickmath.com/math-tutorials/first-degree-equations-first-degree-inequalities-and-there.html#c=solve&v1=-2.4%253D%255Cfrac%257Bx%257D%257B-4%257D&v3=x

Comment: is this a programming-related question ?

Answer (score 0):

Although [Mathematics.SE] related question and not about programming, it might be helpful to learn the steps in solving problems like this

You have (added parenthesis for clarity)

(-2.4) = **z** / (-4)

and you need to isolate the unknown variable **z**. The rule in algebra is whatever you do to one side of the = sign, do unto the other and the equality will hold.

So multiply both sides with (-4) to get

(-2.4) * (-4) = **z**

or multiply both sides with (-1) first to eliminate the negative signs to get

(2.4) = **z** /(4)

and then multiply both sides with (4)

(4)(2.4) = **z**

or

(9.6) = **z**